# Select tags in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a big issue with the select tag. In my view I have the following code:

```
 <%= select 'lw', Logicalwarehouse.all %>
```

In my controller:

```
....
@logical_wh = Logicalwarehouse.find(params['lw'])
    @project.logicalwarehouses << @logical_wh
    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.update_attributes(params[:project])
        flash[:notice] = 'Project was successfully updated.'
        format.html { redirect_to(@project) }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @project.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
...
```

Alternatively, I want use a drop.down menu in my view that will let me choose between all `Logicalwarehouse` objects that will return a chosen object inside the `lw` variable, back to controller. I am having an issue with the view `select` field. Rails returns an error that it has the wrong number of arguments `(2 for 3)`, any suggestions?
Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the name of an attribute that has description of your Logicalwarehouse. I assume it's `name`:

```
<%= select "lw", "id", Logicalwarehouse.all.map{|lw| [ lw.name, lw.id ] } %>
```

**UPD:**
Selected `id` will be available through `params[:lw][:id]`.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What error or something else do you get?

Comment: When I click on submit, rails return an error related to null object. Should I use in controller the following: share [g+] share [fb] share [tw]
 

I've a big issue with select tag. In my view I've the following code:

 <%= select 'lw', Logicalwarehouse.all %>

and in my controller:

....
@logical_wh = Logicalwarehouse.find(params['lw'],['id']) to reflect your view's code?

Comment: Something wrong with your comment but you are right about using `params[:lw][:id]` in your controller (although in slightly different syntax ;))

Comment: Jdoe, it still doesn't works as you said: using params[:lw][:id] in my controller I take the following error:"can't convert Symbol into Integer"

Comment: Paste here your finding statement. It has to be: `Logicalwarehouse.find(params[:lw][:id])`

Comment: Using Logicalwarehouse.find(params[:lw][:id])  I obtain the following error:You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]

Comment: In my view, I'm using '<%= select "lw", "id", Logicalwarehouse.all.map{|lw| [ lw.name, lw.id ] } %>'

Comment: You didn't say a word about your `for_tag`. Maybe something wrong with it? You should have something like `<%= form_tag logicalwarehouse_path, method: :create do %>`. And the `select` should be inside this form.